# MongoDB aggregation: Check if user has already rated a product

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm having some trouble coming up with a solution to this problem by using mongo directly instead of node.

I have a collection of products that have several fields, including an array of ratings. The ratings consist of the id of the user who rated it and the score. They look like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62812fac06f29f5fe874c0db"
  },
  "model": "fire",
  "allRatings": [
    {
      "user_id": "6282962e3aa8163084776092",
      "rating": 9
    },
    {
      "user_id": "62811d520f52b64990a94e99",
      "rating": 6
    }
  ],
}
```

I'd like to return all of the fields, but instead of all the ratings, I just want to return a boolean that shows if the current user, whose ID I have in the code, has already rated the product. I have tried with aggregations, but haven't found any solution that works.

Something like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62812fac06f29f5fe874c0db"
  },
  "model": "fire",
  "hasRated": true,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly you can use this aggregation query:

This query looks for the object you want (matching by _id) and then, into a `$project` stage it set the value `hasRated` if the desired `id` exists into the array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("62812fac06f29f5fe874c0db")
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      model: 1,
      hasRated: {
        "$in": [
          "6282962e3aa8163084776092",
          "$allRatings.user_id"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/96nhfR31xZm)

To do in JS you can simply create the object adding the `id` as a variable (something like this, is pseudocode, not tested):

```js
const id = 'your_id_here'
const agg = [{
    $match: {
      _id: new ObjectId("62812fac06f29f5fe874c0db")
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      model: 1,
      hasRated: {
        "$in": [
          id,
          "$allRatings.user_id"
        ]
      }
    }
  }]

db.aggregate(agg)
```

Comment: The idea is to get all the products, not a specific one, and get also a field that tells me if the current user making the request has already rated the product. I guess I can just remove $match and that should do it.

It seems to work in the link you sent me, but when I do it in node I get a $in requires an array as a second argument. The problem is once I add the array as second argument, it always returns false.

Comment: Yes, removing `$match` should work for all products. Also, what type are the data? Maybe are you comparing string with objectId.